# Performance for delete query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a table with 200,000 records. I want delete some data like below :

```
DELETE FROM Table Where IdColumn IN ( SelectedID )
```

SelectedID fill with my desirable data identities that contains 5000 records. there are 2 approach:

1- I insert 20,000 identity as SelectedID that contains identities of desired 5000 records.

2- I insert only identities of that 5000 records.

question is that what is the difference between two approach? (performance)

Comment: you mean in method one that will be duplicates 15000 duplicates?

Comment: in first approach i have 15000 identity that there is not in Table. but i don't know this. (in my application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance of a large `IN` clause is horrible, this is mainly due to query compile time.  So if you have say a `List<int>` containing the IDs then this:

```
List<int> myIDs = GetIDs(); //20,000
var inList = myIDs.Distinct(); //5,000 distinct IDs
//pass inList to SQL
```

would be much faster than:

```
List<int> inList = GetIDS(); //20,000
//pass inList to SQL
```

If joining is an alternative, if you can get the list of IDs you want to delete by querying, it's better to do a subquery with that, something like this, using a query in the `Where`:

```
DELETE FROM Table 
Where IdColumn IN (Select ID
                   From OtherTable
                   Where Name Like '%DeleteMe%')
```

I'm not sure if your list comes from an external source and can't be determined like this...but if it can, your delete will be extremely faster.

Comment: thanks Nick. I create desired identities in my application by returning a comma separated string.

Comment: Then pass this string to the DELETE procedure, split it inside the sProc with a table-valued UDF and join that with the table you want to delete from.

Comment: @masoud ramezani - Are you not hitting a string length limit with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, if I understand you completely, but I would go for #2 as it seems to be a waste of resources to generate 20.000 rows of which you only need 5.000 instead of inserting only the needed 5.000.

Also, 200.000 rows is a small table. Really!

Comment: yes I know that 200.000 rows is a small table. it is a sample. you can multiply to 100.

Comment: in my application i can search for that 5000 record but it is time wasting therefore i don't search my data and pass all of data identities to IN clause.